# Batch file to move files based on filesize

Tags: batch-file

So this has been irritating me a tad. I'm trying to write a batch file to move over into their own folders based on their filesize. I've started doing this manually, but after thirty minutes I tried to learn how to make a .bat file to cut down on a few hours of work. However, I haven't found any help on Google.com. Normally I look at code and edit it slightly to work, but batch is still very confusing for me, and I haven't found anything similar to what I'm looking for.

So far I have moved 859 32kb files into a folder title "32"
I have done the same with all 431 of the 64kb files, all 91 of the 96kb files, the 30 128kb files, 14 160kb files, 17 192kb files, 9 224kb files, then 258kb-1376kb all have around 4-5 each before it grows exponentially again up to 912mb, and I stopped at 640kb.

So there is a pattern, I just need a .bat code to move these files into folders named after their filesize. I imagine in another coding language, a loop doing what I want would look something like this,

```
dim strFS as String
strFS = "file".filesize
move "file" to /"strFS"
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a file move could be done with following commented batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*) do (

    rem Divide file size by 32768
    set /A "BlockSize=%%~zF/32768"
    rem Calculate remainder of above division.
    set /A "Remainder=!BlockSize!*32678-%%~zF"
    rem Multiply result with 32 and round up to 32, 64, 96, 128, ...
    if "!Remainder!"=="0" ( set "Add=0" ) else ( set "Add=32" )
    set /A "FolderName=BlockSize*32+Add"

    rem Move the file to appropriate directory which fails if the
    rem directory does not already exist. In this case create the
    rem directory and execute move command once again.
    move "%%~nxF" !FolderName!\ 2>nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        md !FolderName!
        if not errorlevel 1 (
            move "%%~nxF" !FolderName!
        ) else (
            echo Could not create directory !FolderName! for file %%~nxF
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

The batch file cannot be in the current working directory because it would move itself which is of course not a good idea.

Help for the commands **for**, **if**, **md**, **move**, **set** and **setlocal** can be read by opening a command prompt and entering those commands with parameter `/?` appended or as parameter after command **help**, for example `for /?` or `help for`.